# Querying and Combining Different Tables

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have three data tables that I want to query but then group them together based on a common field, which is a date field. The schema for the three tables look like the following:

Sugar Table

```
Name                  Type
sugar_id (Primary)    int(11)
user_id (Foreign Key) int(11)
read_date             date
read_time             time
reading               int(11)
```

Pressure Table

```
Name                  Type
pressure_id (Primary) int(11)
user_id (Foreign Key) int(11)
read_date             date
read_time             time
systolic              int(11)
diastolic             int(11)
```

Dietary Table

```
Name                  Type
dietar_id (Primary)   int(11)
user_id (Foreign Key) int(11)
entry_date            date
entry_time            time
quantity              varchar(64)
food                  varchar(64)
notes                 varchar(1000)
```

As mentioned the date field that I want to group by in all three tables (`read_date` in sugar and pressure and `entry_date` in dietary).

What I would like to do is for every date, in every table return a list item if there is an entry for the respective table and then a list with list items for every row that contains share the same date. An example would be:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    Sugar
    <ul>
      <li>[reading] taken at [time]</li>
  </li>
  <li>
    Pressure
    <ul>
      <li>[systolic]/[diastolic] taken at [time]</li>
      <li>[systolic]/[diastolic] taken at [time]</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    Dietary
    <ul>
      <li>[quantity] [food] eaten at [time]</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

My initial thought was to create a collection that stored the DOM elements, query every table individually, iterating through each row, check if the date exists in the collection, if so then append the parent `<li>` to the respective item in the collection, and if not then create a new item in the array that stores the date as the key and creates the parent `<li>` as the value.

Then I started to think that I could probably do this using just SQL. However, my SQL is not that strong and to be honest I'm not sure if returning the DOM in a query is the best way to go.

So my question to y'all is two-fold. First, which way should I go: using PHP/jQuery or SQL to build the DOM? Second, if the answer is the latter how should I tackle this problem considering that my date fields are not named the same and the schema of the tables vary enough to make things complicated for a union?

The languages that I'm using are: jQuery 3.4.1, PHP 7.3.0, and MySQL (though I'm unsure of the version).

Comment: I really wouldn't try to generate DOM in SQL. It will be far easier in PHP (or any language that understands looping).

Comment: I can see that there is not table inter connection they only have userid

Answer (score -1):

Select record using inner join query by user_id and use group by function to sorting the record table.user_id,table.read_date